# Updated to Wordpress 3.0.5 and all my work is gone?

Tags: wordpress, backups

I updated my website from Wordpress 3.0.4 to 3.0.5 and all my work is gone! Can go back somehow? How can it overwrite everything?

The theme I used for the site is a copy of Twenty Ten and then I modified it.

Please help me....

Comment: You may want to try asking at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. That site is dedicated to WordPress.

Comment: Well, if you copied Twenty Ten and then modified it the copy should still be there. What's in wp-content/themes folder? Can you see your copied theme? How did you copy it?

Answer (score 2):

If you modify Twenty Ten, you must change the name and the details of the theme in style.css and also change the name of the theme folder itself to something other than "twentyten" or automatic updates will overwrite the folder. Have backup?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking to see if your posts etc are in the database? It may be that word press just can't connect to  the right tables? It may have renamed some tables? so have a look through the database using something like phpMyAdmin.

Do you have a backup that you can restore? I think that it is advised that you always backup before an update. Sorry it that is a kick in the teeth if you haven't backed up, but if it has over written everything there isn't much that you can do.

I doubt that the theme had anything to do with losing the data. The themes just shows the data in various ways.

Comment: it's not the posts i want, it the design. all php-files and the css-files are overwritten. But I guess that's what happens when u update without backup.....

Comment: Ah ok, in that case I think you may be stuck, unless you have a copy on your local machine. The only other thing I can think of is trying to google your site and then selecting the cached copy and hoping that it hasn't been updated in the cache and then saving those files. It's a long tho though and you would have to add the wordpress php code back in. Hope you get it sorted

Comment: If google doesn't have a cached copy, the wayback machine probably will have - http://www.archive.org/web/web.php, although again you will need to manually copy the code back.